# Is there a way to create step functions graph using CDK?

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-cdk

Currently step functions graph are defined in json using ASL (Amazon States Language).
There is no good way to to unit testing of the graphs being created and we have to rely on running the graph with mocked/some implementation of lambda functions on aws account.
With launch of AWS CDK, is it possible to have the step function graphs also defined in high level language and do unit testing, mocking etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you given the [`@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-stepfunctions-readme.html) library a try?

Copying the example code from the documentation here for posterity:

```
const submitLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'SubmitLambda', { ... });
const getStatusLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 'CheckLambda', { ... });

const submitJob = new stepfunctions.Task(this, 'Submit Job', {
    resource: submitLambda,
    // Put Lambda's result here in the execution's state object
    resultPath: '$.guid',
});

const waitX = new stepfunctions.Wait(this, 'Wait X Seconds', { secondsPath: '$.wait_time' });

const getStatus = new stepfunctions.Task(this, 'Get Job Status', {
    resource: getStatusLambda,
    // Pass just the field named "guid" into the Lambda, put the
    // Lambda's result in a field called "status"
    inputPath: '$.guid',
    resultPath: '$.status',
});

const jobFailed = new stepfunctions.Fail(this, 'Job Failed', {
    cause: 'AWS Batch Job Failed',
    error: 'DescribeJob returned FAILED',
});

const finalStatus = new stepfunctions.Task(this, 'Get Final Job Status', {
    resource: getStatusLambda,
    // Use "guid" field as input, output of the Lambda becomes the
    // entire state machine output.
    inputPath: '$.guid',
});

const definition = submitJob
    .next(waitX)
    .next(getStatus)
    .next(new stepfunctions.Choice(this, 'Job Complete?')
        // Look at the "status" field
        .when(stepfunctions.Condition.stringEquals('$.status', 'FAILED'), jobFailed)
        .when(stepfunctions.Condition.stringEquals('$.status', 'SUCCEEDED'), finalStatus)
        .otherwise(waitX));

new stepfunctions.StateMachine(this, 'StateMachine', {
    definition,
    timeoutSec: 300
});
```