# Can a Amazon States Language json file be generated from CDK step functions TS file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

If I have a CDK *.ts file that defines my AWS Step Functions, is it possible to generate an Amazon States Language asl.json file that I can use it to visualize that step function process (using the AWS Toolkit for VS)?

I took a look at: [Is there a way of running AWS Step Functions locally when defined by CDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63348917/is-there-a-way-of-running-aws-step-functions-locally-when-defined-by-cdk), [Is there a way to create step functions graph using CDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587097/is-there-a-way-to-create-step-functions-graph-using-cdk), and the AWS CDK for Step Functions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-stepfunctions-readme.html but none of those resources indicated a process to generate that asl.json file.  The AWS Step Function module has an Import, what I am looking for is essentially, the reverse or an Export.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio Code supports visualization of CDK state machines. Run `cdk synth` then the state machine resource will appear in the CDK explorer. Right click on it to display the graph.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what your looking for, but check out this [Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71003441/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-amazon-state-language-json-representation-of-a-state-m).

From this you would be able to get the Amazon State Language JSON of your state machine that is defined in your CDK *.ts file and do whatever you want with it upon deployment.

If you wanted to see the JSON that is created just to visualize it though, you can always go to the AWS Console > Step Functions > [Your State Machine] > Definition tab, to see the asl.json